# Maya script that renders to frame buffer keeps grabbing focus on windows

Tags: python, maya

I have a script in Maya (python) that renders a series of frames to the V-ray frame buffer, one for each render layer. It is working well, but when switching render layers and launching the next render, Maya grabs focus, interrupting whatever task the artist had moved on to while the script was running. I would like this to be a background task.  Maya is running on Windows.

```py
import maya
import maya.cmds as cmds
import re
from functools import partial
import sys
from datetime import datetime

global cancel
cancel = 0

print 'batch_review'

def no_cam_window_popup(no_cam_set_list):
    #print no_cam_set_list
    cmds.window(title = 'WARNING: NO CAMERAS LINKED TO LAYERS', width = 300, height = 75, sizeable = False)
    cmds.columnLayout("mainColumn", adjustableColumn = True)
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout01", numberOfColumns = 15, parent = "mainColumn")
    cmds.text(label = ("no cam set for layers:"))
    for layer in no_cam_set_list:
        cmds.text(label = ('' + layer + ', '),font = 'boldLabelFont')
    cmds.showWindow()

def renderThumbs(checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,checkBoxRenderRegion,intField_res,floatField_thrhld,*args):
    global cancel
    cams = cmds.ls(type = "camera")
    cancel = 0
    popup_win = 0
    no_cam_set_list = []
    cmds.loadPlugin('vrayformaya', quiet=True)
    cmds.pluginInfo('vrayformaya', edit=True, autoload=True)
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.ren", "vray", type = "string")

    curLay = cmds.editRenderLayerGlobals( currentRenderLayer = True, query = True )
    changeLay = curLay

    rls = cmds.ls(type = "renderLayer")
    renCams = cmds.ls(type = "camera")
    renCam = "persp"

    lowBut = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = True, query = True)
    midBut = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = True, query = True)
    highBut = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = True, query = True)
    globopt_cache_geom_plugins = cmds.getAttr('vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins')
    #print 'globopt_cache_geom_plugins = ',globopt_cache_geom_plugins

    print " "
    print "-- batch_review --"

    res = cmds.intField(intField_res, v = True, query = True)
    thr = cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld, v = True,query = True)

    if lowBut == 1:
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.dmcThreshold",thr)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.width", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.height", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins",1)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_ray_maxIntens_on",1)
        #cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins',globopt_cache_geom_plugins)
        print " "
        print "---"
        print "quality = %s, dmcThreshold = %s"%(res,thr)
    if midBut == 1:
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.dmcThreshold",thr)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.width", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.height", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins",1)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_ray_maxIntens_on",1)
        #cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins',globopt_cache_geom_plugins)
        print " "
        print "---"
        print "quality = %s, dmcThreshold = %s"%(res,thr)
    if highBut == 1:
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.dmcThreshold",thr)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.width", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.height", res)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins",1)
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.globopt_ray_maxIntens_on",1)
        #cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.globopt_cache_geom_plugins',globopt_cache_geom_plugins)
        print " "
        print "---"
        print "quality = %s, dmcThreshold = %s"%(res,thr)

    print "--- "
    print " "

    for rl in rls:
        found_cam = 0
        if rl != "defaultRenderLayer" and cancel == 0:
            rlState = cmds.getAttr(rl + ".renderable")
            if rlState == 1:
                print ' '
                print "rende layer = ",rl
                cmds.editRenderLayerGlobals( currentRenderLayer = rl )
                for cam in cams:
                    camState = cmds.getAttr(cam + ".renderable")
                    if camState == 1:
                        rrState = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxRenderRegion,value = True,query = True)
                        reg = cmds.vray("vfbControl","-getregion")
                        if  rrState == 0:
                            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion","reset")
                        if  rrState == 1:
                            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregionenabled",1)
                            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",reg[0],reg[1],reg[2],reg[3])
                        mayaString = "renderWindowRenderCamera render renderView " + cam
                        print 'using ' + cam + ' for ' + rl
                        maya.mel.eval(mayaString)
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historysave")
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historyselect",0)
                        dte = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                        editStr = dte + " ,render layer: " + rl + " , " + "cam: " + cam
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historycomment", editStr)
                        print " "
                        found_cam = 1
                if found_cam == 0:
                    print 'no camera link found, using persp cam for ',rl
                    cam = 'persp'
                    rrState = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxRenderRegion,value = True,query = True)
                    reg = cmds.vray("vfbControl","-getregion")
                    if  rrState == 0:
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion","reset")
                    if  rrState == 1:
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregionenabled",1)
                        cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",reg[0],reg[1],reg[2],reg[3])
                    mayaString = "renderWindowRenderCamera render renderView " + cam
                    maya.mel.eval(mayaString)
                    cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historysave")
                    cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historyselect",0)
                    dte = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                    editStr = dte + " ,render layer: " + rl + " , " + "cam: " + cam
                    cmds.vray("vfbControl", "-historycomment", editStr)
                    popup_win = 1
                    no_cam_set_list.append(rl)
    #if popup_win == 1:
        #no_cam_window_popup(no_cam_set_list)


def checkBoxCheckLow(checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld,*args):
    global cancel
    lowButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = True, query = True)
    midButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = True, query = True)
    highButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = True, query = True)

    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.intField(intField_res, v = 800,edit = True)
    cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld, v = .1,edit = True )
    cancel = 0

def checkBoxCheckMid(checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld,*args):
    global cancel
    lowButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = True, query = True)
    midButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = True, query = True)
    highButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = True, query = True)

    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.intField(intField_res, v = 1000,edit = True)
    cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld, v = .5,edit = True )
    cancel = 0

def checkBoxCheckHigh(checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld,*args):
    global cancel
    lowButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = True, query = True)
    midButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = True, query = True)
    highButVal = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh,value = True, query = True)

    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid,value = False, edit = True)
    cmds.intField(intField_res, v = 2000,edit = True)
    cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld, v = .008,edit = True )
    cancel = 0

def checkBoxAOVchange(checkBoxAOV,*args):
    checkBoxAOVval = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxAOV,value = True,query = True)
    if checkBoxAOVval == 1:
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.relements_enableall", 1)
    if checkBoxAOVval == 0:
        cmds.setAttr("vraySettings.relements_enableall", 0)

def rrCheckbox(checkBoxRenderRegion,reg,*args):
    global gReg
    zeroes = ['0','0','0','0']
    tRes = cmds.vray("vfbControl","-getregion")
    if tRes != zeroes:
        gReg = tRes
    rrstate = cmds.checkBox(checkBoxRenderRegion,value = True,query = True)
    if rrstate == 0:
        if gReg != zeroes:
            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",gReg[0],gReg[1],gReg[2],gReg[3])
        else:
            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",reg[0],reg[1],reg[2],reg[3])
        cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion","reset")
    if rrstate == 1:
        cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregionenabled",1)
        if gReg != zeroes:
            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",gReg[0],gReg[1],gReg[2],gReg[3])
        else:
            cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion",reg[0],reg[1],reg[2],reg[3])
    return(reg)

def cancelOPs(*args):
    global cancel
    cancel = 1
    raise Exception("quitting renders")

def set_threshhold(floatField_thrhld,*args):
    threshhold_value = cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld,value = True,query = True)
    cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.dmcThreshold',threshhold_value)

def set_resolution(intField_res,*args):
    intField_res_value = cmds.intField(intField_res,value = True,query = True)
    cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.width',intField_res_value)
    cmds.setAttr('vraySettings.height',intField_res_value)

def renthumbsWin():
    name = "Batch_Review"
    global gReg
    gReg = ('0','0','0','0')
    zeroes = ('0','0','0','0')
    windowSize = (200,100)
    if (cmds.window(name, exists = True)):
        cmds.deleteUI(name)
    window = cmds.window(name, title = name, width = 350, height = 50,bgc = (.2,.2,.2), s = False)
    cmds.columnLayout("mainColumn", adjustableColumn = True)
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout01", numberOfColumns = 15, parent = "mainColumn")
    cmds.text(label = "preset quality:  ")
    checkBoxLow = cmds.checkBox(label = "low", value = False)
    checkBoxMid = cmds.checkBox(label = "mid", value = True,)
    checkBoxHigh = cmds.checkBox(label = "high", value = False)
    cmds.text(label = "                             ")
    cmds.text(label = "resolution:  ")
    intField_res = cmds.intField(v = 1000,width = 45)
    #print 'intField_res = ',intField_res
    cmds.intField(intField_res, changeCommand = partial(set_resolution,intField_res),edit = True)
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    cmds.text(label = "threshold:  ")
    floatField_thrhld = cmds.floatField(v = .5,width = 45)
    cmds.floatField(floatField_thrhld, changeCommand = partial(set_threshhold,floatField_thrhld),edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxLow, changeCommand = partial(checkBoxCheckLow,checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld), edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxMid, changeCommand = partial(checkBoxCheckMid,checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld),edit = True)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxHigh, changeCommand = partial(checkBoxCheckHigh,checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,intField_res,floatField_thrhld),edit = True)
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout02", numberOfColumns = 10, parent = "mainColumn")
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout03", numberOfColumns = 5, parent = "mainColumn")
    renderButton = cmds.button(label = "render",width = 100, bgc = (.6,.8,1) )
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    cmds.button(label = "cancel renders", command = partial(cancelOPs),bgc = (1,.3,.3) )
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout04", numberOfColumns = 10, parent = "mainColumn")
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout05", numberOfColumns = 10, parent = "mainColumn")
    checkBoxRenderRegion = cmds.checkBox(label = "use render region", value = False)
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    cmds.text(label = "  ")
    reg = cmds.vray("vfbControl","-getregion")
    if reg != gReg and reg != zeroes:
        gReg = reg
    cmds.vray("vfbControl","-setregion","reset")
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxRenderRegion,changeCommand = partial(rrCheckbox,checkBoxRenderRegion,reg),edit = True)
    cmds.rowLayout("nameRowLayout06", numberOfColumns = 10, parent = "mainColumn")
    AOVstate = cmds.getAttr("vraySettings.relements_enableall")
    checkBoxAOV = cmds.checkBox(label = "elements", value = AOVstate)
    cmds.checkBox(checkBoxAOV,changeCommand = partial(checkBoxAOVchange,checkBoxAOV),edit = True)
    cmds.button(renderButton,command = partial(renderThumbs,checkBoxLow,checkBoxMid,checkBoxHigh,checkBoxRenderRegion,intField_res,floatField_thrhld),edit = True)
    cmds.showWindow()

def main():
    renthumbsWin()

main()
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: I added code to the question, thank you.